# Prevent if statement from running while already running (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, settimeout, wait, interrupt

I have an **if** statement which looks something like this:

```
if( extra.RewardId === "idnumberhere") {
        egg.classList.add("bounce");
        setTimeout (() => {
            egg.classList.remove("bounce");
            petEffects.innerText = `Working`;
            petEffects.classList.add("typing");
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout (() => {
            petEffects.innerText = ``;
            petEffects.classList.remove("typing");
        }, 5000);
}
```

It is a bit longer than this, but the main problem is that it is interrupting itself if I trigger the **if** statement a second time, too soon.

How would go about making the second instance wait until the first **if** statement fully runs its course, and those 5000ms pass before the next instance begins?

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/d2jhmec1/2/

I have made a safe to share JSfiddle. Clicking the button will show what I'm currently working with. When clicked twice, it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a Boolean flag that will tell you whether to run the code or not.

Something like this:

```
let canAddBounce = true;
let canRemoveBounce = true;

if(extra.RewardId === "idnumberhere") {
    if (canAddBounce) {
        canAddBounce = false;
        egg.classList.add("bounce");
        setTimeout (() => {
            egg.classList.remove("bounce");
            petEffects.innerText = `Working`;
            petEffects.classList.add("typing");
            canAddBounce = true;
        }, 3000);
    }
    if (canRemoveBounce) {
        canRemoveBounce = false;
        setTimeout (() => {
            petEffects.innerText = ``;
            petEffects.classList.remove("typing");
            canRemoveBounce = true;
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that didn't work. Perhaps because my real code is a bit longer? I made a safe to share JSdiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2jhmec1/2/ Clicking the button, following your approach, still leads to interruption -- and furthermore doesn't seem to queue up the next instance.

Comment: I'm confused as to your intentions. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you simply trying to run these setTimeout statements one after the other?

Comment: They currently do that. However, my issue is the function running before the first run through of events finishes. If I click the button while the animations are playing out, everything breaks. I want it so that if I click the button while the animations are playing, it will wait until the first run through finishes, and then it will run through the second time.